# Cannot login to MySQL from WAMP but login to MariaDB works

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, mariadb, wamp

I installed WAMP and I am trying to login to phpmyadmin. I am not able to login to MySQL, but I can login to MariaDB.
I did many configuration changes but I am not able to login.

```
$mariaFirst = ($wampConf['SupportMySQL'] == 'on' && $wampConf['SupportMariaDB'] == 'on' && $wampConf['mariaPortUsed'] == $wampConf['mysqlDefaultPort']) ? true : false;
if($wampConf['SupportMySQL'] == 'on') {
/* Server: localhost [1] */
    $i++;
    if($mariaFirst) $i++;
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['verbose'] = 'MySQL';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '127.0.0.1';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['port'] = $wampConf['mysqlPortUsed'];
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'root';

    // Hidden databases in PhpMyAdmin left panel
    //$cfg['Servers'][$i]['hide_db'] = '(information_schema|mysql|performance_schema|sys)';

    // Allow connection without password
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;
}
/* Server: localhost [2] */
if($wampConf['SupportMariaDB'] =='on') {
    $i++;
    if($mariaFirst) $i -= 2;
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['verbose'] = 'MariaDB';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '127.0.0.1';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['port'] = $wampConf['mariaPortUsed'];
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'root';

    // Hidden databases in PhpMyAdmin left panel
    //$cfg['Servers'][$i]['hide_db'] = '(information_schema|mysql|performance_schema|sys)';
    // Allow connection without password
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;
}

// Suppress Warning about pmadb tables
$cfg['PmaNoRelation_DisableWarning'] = true;

// To have PRIMARY & INDEX in table structure export
$cfg['Export']['sql_drop_table'] = true;
$cfg['Export']['sql_if_not_exists'] = true;
```

I changed many parameters and still I am not able to login to MySQL, but I can login to MariaDB

Comment: what is the error from the php error logs? What PHP version? What does `SHOW CREATE USER root` show on the MySQL?

Comment: I am able to login to MariaDB even without entering password

Comment: `mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)`

Comment: What makes you think that both a MySQL and a MariaDB server a running?

Comment: I am trying to logint to phpmyadmin in wamp, I can see mysql and mariadb option while logging in..Mariadb dont require a password..mysql is shoing error while logging

Answer (score 0):

Guys I found out the solution. I had MySQL Workbench running with same connection settings. So I removed that connection and I was able to use MySQL in WAMP